# Allow only one marker in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I know that exists some threads about this subject, but I believe that this is a bit different, because, all threads is about one marker clicking on the map, but this is a only marker in each time. Check out this code below

```
...
var x = map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), 17);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map: map,
        title: 'Map Tracker',
});
...
```

In each 30 seconds, this code is called with different [lat] and [lng] values, but all old markers still visible and I don't know how to remove them, I want only one marker per result. Also, I already tried map.clearOverlays() but still not working anymore.

Can you help me?

Comment: The answer is the same as the other questions.  Either remove the marker from the map then overwrite it with the new one or move it to the new location.

Comment: I already tried! Still not working, have no errors :)

Comment: The flood persists: http://prntscr.com/hib0s6

Comment: I can't execute a picture. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (with some attempt to remove the marker)

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API has an API call that is used to set [visible](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) or not, before rebinding x to a new map, you could set the visibility to false.

```
...
if (x !== undefined && x !== null) { x.setVisible(false) }

var x = map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), 17);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    map: map,
    title: 'Map Tracker',
});
...
```

Comment: Still not working... The flood persists: http://prntscr.com/hib0s6

Comment: hmm, any chance we could see more of your code? Generally following something like this should work, I think it is around that you are replacing the existing marker variable.

Comment: Not sure why you are checking `x` and attempting to call `setVisible` on it, `map.setCenter` doesn't return anything, per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Map) its return value is: `Return Value:  None`